# Receiving data from website form to c# application

Tags: c#, html, web

It seems that the HTTPListener class was recommended, but apparently, it only returns another web page to the request.

How do i go about posting data from my form in my website and processing them in my c# application.

Any tutorials or simple examples will do.

I would have a form like this in my web page

```
<form action = "C# application" method = "post">
<input type = "text" /> 
<input type = "submit" />
```

The text data should be sent to my C# application for processing

Comment: Can you please clarify your question: are you trying to create your own web server (like IIS), or scape/crawl web pages, or automate filling out web forms? Or maybe something totally different?

Comment: It seem like regular ASP.Net WebForms or MVC web site written in C# may work, but you want C# application... Where "application" requirement comes from?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is using a database.

Create remote database which both web application and windows application can communicate
Use timer object to frequently query the database and display new messages are required
Complex solution involves creating UDP/TCP connections between applications.

Comment: I have thought of this solution but would prefer a solution where the website can post data to a C# application

Answer (score 1):

using httphandlers could help you or you can create webservice by WCF to handle and process your requests.

Comment: Sorry could you shed more light on this. Googling does not really help much